# How to stop setInterval();?

Tags: javascript

I have like...

```
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="updater.js"></script>
```

The updater I want to get data from my .php file, so probably something like...

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(html) {
             // html is a string of all output of the server script.
            $("#div").html(html);
       }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Then, obviously enough the test.php's page will result.

But, I want to STOP the setInterval(); WHEN someone clicks on a comment button (textarea). I'm aware, there's some on here; but they're not working?

Comment: [`Window.clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) mate

Comment: P.S. That's not my actual code; just some random junk. But, that's the kind of format I have.

Comment: For a full demo on how to stop an interval see the the JavaScript MDN docs on `setInterVal`, specifically [**Example 2**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval#Example_2.3A_Alternating_two_colors) - `The following example will continue to call the flashtext() function once a second, until you clear the intervalID by clicking the Stop button.` - Relevant Code is in the stop button click. - Hope this helps :)

Comment: @AwesomeE: I'm not sure why you feel your questions is not answered.  Can you tell us what else you are looking for please that `clearInterval` does not do? The code you need, as far as we can tell, is in the linked "possible" duplicate(s) but also in every answer, unless there are further requirements in addition to what you stated. `clearInterval(intervalId)` will stop the interval - How you invoke it is up to you. If you want simply a complete copy-paste solution, see [**this**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 5):

[`Window.clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval), It accepts an `intervalID` is the identifier of the repeated action you want to cancel. This ID is returned from `setInterval().`

Example

```
var interVal = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(html) {
             // html is a string of all output of the server script.
            $("#div").html(html);
       }
    });
}, 5000);

clearInterval(interVal); //Call the method when you want to clear it.
```

Answer (score 3):

The `setInterval` function will return an integer which identifies that interval. Save that integer for later use, and when you want to clear the interval pass it into `clearInterval` as an argument.

E.g.:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(html) {
             // html is a string of all output of the server script.
            $("#div").html(html);
       }
    });
}, 5000);
```

And then when you want to cancel it:

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval). It takes the Id of interval & clears it.

Get your `setInterval` in a variable.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){...},time);
```

After clicking on button just do

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/37/)